# PCA trained model and then back to original feature space

Tags: python, classification, pca

I tried to predict special movement with my smartphone. Therfore I have developed an application with creates a dataset containing acceleration, gyroscope, magneticfiled etc.
The Problem is, I dont dont realy know which are good features
Thats why i tried to use PCA

so far no problems

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(0.95) # i don't want to lose too much information

.. split recorded data in train and test samples

pc_test = pca.fit_transform(data_test)
pc_train = pca.fit_transform(data_train)
```

and fit the data to Random Forest or Ridge Regression etc...

But now i have the problem that all my trained classifier, are only working on pca transformed data.
This means i have to do pca on my phone to do my intended prediction.
Is this the correct way to proceed or have i missed something?

I thought about pca like one time analytics tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I do not think, it is always a good idea to set a static variance ratio from the beginning like 0.95. Holding as many information as possible(up to all the dimensions you have originally) sometimes lead not to  to the best Result/model since you are trying PCA here. I would try a series of variance ratios like:

```
import numpy as np
n_s = np.linspace(0.65, 0.85, num=21)
for n in n_s:
    pca = PCA(n_components=n)
    #...
```

and look at the results Than you can set your variance/number of components (which generates the highest accuracy in your model) to a scalar.It is a important point in ML. To your question: Most likely you are not going to do PCA and even modelling on your phone, you only are going to use the resulting model at the end. You gonna want to have your training data set as large as possible(that leads to better accuracies), as far as your computing hardware allows. That "superior" hardware cannot be your mobile phone.

Comment: thanks for reply, but my model is trained on principal components. I cant fit my incoming data directly to my model (because of the missing transformation) or is it somehow possible?

Comment: you are right, you cannot feed the incoming data directly to the model. It should go down the stack and pass through the pca *model*(transform) before the model. let's say your input is `Xi` and your trained model ls `clf`:
`Xi_new=pca.transform(Xi)
clf.fit(Xi_new)`